# Error running Stanford NER model 3.6.0

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using NER module 3.3.1 with no problems, but when I'm trying to use NER module 3.6.0 (or any higher than last version) I got the following exception:

```
[java] Loading classifier from ./lib/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer (in module: java.base) cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.FeatureFactory (in module: Unnamed Module)
 [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2606)
 [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1622)
 [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1677)
 [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1664)
 [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2832)
 [java]     at sss.texttools.Cleaner.ner(Cleaner.java:67)
 [java]     at sss.lucene.LuceneManager.getAnswer(LuceneManager.java:114)
 [java]     at sss.main.Main.main(Main.java:114)
```

Here is the code:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Cleaner {

    private String serializedClassifier="./lib/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

    public String ner(String str) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(serializedClassifier);
        String taggedStr = classifier.classifyToString(str);
        return taggedStr;
}
```

PS 1: I'm using java version 1.8, and follwing the file NERDemo.java.

PS 2: I get the same exception on the PoS Tagger in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my case.

In my classpath I had this package "stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04" and because they have some .jars in commun it was causing the problem.

So the new versions of the Stanford NER model 3.6.0 and Stanford POS Tagger model 3.6.0 are working it just dont work with older versions of Stanford packages.